# Error: "'<' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to append XML into a node

```
            #Insert Data into template
            foreach ($listXml in $webConfig.Lists.List)
            {
                $dataXml =""

                if ($listXml.IncludeData)
                {
                    $list = Get-PnPList -Web $web -Identity $listXml.Name       
                    $list.ParentWeb.Context.Load($list.Fields)
                    $list.ParentWeb.Context.ExecuteQuery()

                    Write-Host $list.Title
                    $listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list.Title

                    $dataXml += '<pnp:DataRows xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">'


                    foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
                    {

                       $dataXml += "<pnp:DataRow>"


                       foreach($fieldValue in $listItem.FieldValues.GetEnumerator())
                       {

                            $fieldName = $fieldValue.Key #($list.Fields | Where {$_.InternalName -eq $fieldValue.Key}).Title

                            if ($fieldName -notin "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri", "ContentTypeID", "_ModerationComments", "File_x0020_Type", "ID","Author","Created","Editor","Modified By","_HasCopyDestinations",
            "_CopySource", "owshiddenversion", "WorkflowVersion", "_UIVersion", "_UIVersionString", "Attachments", "FileRef", "FileDirRef", "_ModerationStatus", "InstanceID", "WorkflowInstanceID", "Order", "GUID", "Workflow Instance ID", "URL Path",
            "Path", "Modified", "Created", "Item Type", "Sort Type", "Name",  "Unique Id",  "Client Id",  "ProgId", "ScopeId", "Property Bag", "_Level", "_IsCurrentVersion","ItemChildCount",
            "FolderChildCount","Restricted", "OriginatorId", 'ContentVersion;', "_ComplianceFlags", "_ComplianceTag", "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime", "_ComplianceTagUserId",
            "AccessPolicy", "AppAuthor","AppEditor", "SMTotalSize", "SMLastModifiedDate", "SMTotalFileStreamSize", "SMTotalFileCount", "Last_x0020_Modified", "Created_x0020_Date", "FSObjType", "SortBehavior",  "FileLeafRef", "UniqueId", "SyncClientId", "MetaInfo",  "NoExecute","ContentVersion" )
                            {

                                if ($fieldName -ne "" -and $fieldName -ne $null)
                                {                                        

                                    $dataXml += "<pnp:DataValue FieldName=""$fieldName"" >" 
                                    $dataXml += $fieldValue.Value
                                    $dataXml += "</pnp:DataValue>"

                                }
                            }

                       }

                       $dataXml += "</pnp:DataRow>"

                    }

                    $dataXml += "</pnp:DataRows>"

                }

                $filename = $FILENAME
                [xml]$templateXml = Get-Content "$path\Templates\$template\$environmentName\$filename"
                Write-Host $list.Title -ForegroundColor yellow
                $xmlList = $templateXml.Provisioning.Templates.ProvisioningTemplate.Lists.ListInstance | where { $_.Title -eq $list.Title}

                clear-content "templates/log.txt"
                add-content "templates/log.txt" $dataXml
                [xml]$XmlData = $dataXml

                $xmlList.AppendChild([System.Xml.XmlNode]$templateXml.ImportNode($XmlData.DataRows,$true))

                $templateXml.Save("$path\Templates\$template\$environmentName\$filename")
```

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot Powershell:
[image]

Comment: Consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Powershell so I can't be definitive, but I can make a good guess. The only place where ";" is significant in XML is to terminate an entity reference like `&nbsp;`, so I suspect that your "XML" contains an `&` that isn't the start of a well-formed entity reference. And looking at your code, you're constructing XML by concatenating string values found in some input, and you appear to be making no attempt to escape special characters, so if there's an `&` in an input string, you're not escaping it as `&amp;`.

Comment: You're right in that there are quite a few values where the string contains "&". So using powershell, should I be doing something a long the lines of  `$dataXml += $fieldValue.Value -replace  "&", "&amp;"`

Comment: You need to escape `&` as `&amp;`, `<` as `&lt;`, and `]]>` as `]]&gt;` (most people escape every `>` as `&gt;` because it's easier, but it's only absolutely necessary with `]]>`) You also need to do escaping in attribute values.